# Can't connect to my company ArcGIS Online REST Server on QGIS 3.32/28

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, token

I've used the ArcGIS REST Server for many months in the past year to load feature layers and tables on QGIS and work with them, then in early December, out of the blue, I couldn't connect anymore to the service. I'm running QGIS on Windows 11 on a company laptop.

What surprises me is that I have a QGIS installation on a Linux Server with the same connection configuration, and it is still working smoothly.

The way the connection is set up is as follows:

1. A mobile application was created inside my company's ArcGIS Online
   environment as an OAuth 2.0 tool.

[image]
Along the Client ID, Client Secret, and
Temporary Token, under the "Application" tab on the settings, I've specified the URL (https://qgis.org), and the redirect URLs as follows:

```
https://qgis.org 

http://127.0.0.1:7070 

https://127.0.0.1:7070
```

2. On QGIS side, I created an ArcGIS REST Server Connection as follows:

Name: MyCompany_AGOL

URL: https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e74a9c11dcf8449e5cb5595a17b41106 ##the URL of the OAuth 2.0 application on AGOL

Community Endpoint URL: https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/community

Content Endpoint URL: https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content

[image]

Then I set an Authentication configuration where I Specified:

Name: MyCompanyUTL

ID: Mportal

By setting the OAuth2 authentication I set the rest of the parametres:

Grant flow: Authorization Code

Request URL:  https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/authorize

Token URL:  https://mycompany.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token

Client ID and secret from the mobile application

Token header: X-Esri-Authorization

[image]

At the moment I connect to the Rest Server the configuration asks me to login to my AGOL user and when it is successful I get this message:

[image]

This happened until early December and now it is only happening on the Linux Server.
On Windows 11, regardless of the version of QGIS I use, regardless of the laptop I use, or regardless of which mobile application I use, I get this error as soon as I log in with my credentials:

[image]

The URL I get is as follows: http://127.0.0.1:7070/?code=oseOSaaZ_7NxIEERg1F2WNuLTqxQbYR3D2BMunh4RqMxwHpks7PJBdQe5pYjrHzDqhEnTlES86sK0nH4JUb5hLgwWA6tooRZTTBNqDaqIU8veaZ5Xf-D13MyWaM0Z93HnJT8y5-HTmK2m9o7-dYISZnX5SrhYKnf_BEOdm0_zOxEevXzb96VsRAV66neDt36v1IJYU6kbVdA8V61aC0_A9N0B8_YTkSTHTtBNrBuzi8.

How can I solve this problem? Is there anyone else experiencing the same issue? I can't use QGIS on the Linux Server undefinitely because other users have to access the server and my company does not have ArcGIS Pro licenses. I know there is an ArcGIS API connector plugin on QGIS but it is outdated.

Comment: sounds like your company now has a proxy server for windows based pc's implemented

Comment: @Mapperz so that should explain also why it didn't work from my personal laptop either? Even if I'm not directly connected to my company's server, the ArcGIS domain of my company is on top of that server.